# How can I pipeline multiple soap requests using soap UI

Tags: soapui

Hi I have 3 soap requests. 
Say.
Req1 
Req2
Req3

I need to run them in an order. How can I do that using Soap UI

Comment: By the way, there is a 
*Software Quality Assurance & Testing* community available at http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ that might be better suited for questions like this one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create TestSuites in SoapUI. TestSuite is a logical grouping of test cases.
While executing a test suite you have the option to run the test cases in sequence or parallel.

[image]

If you also need to pipeline the response of one request to another you would need [property transfer](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html).

For further reading you can refer this [link](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html).